# Append a text File inside a Zip

Tags: perl

I have zip file inside a Text file (file.txt inside a file.zip) and I would like to append to this file another text file file.txt outside the zip file.
How can I do this? Is there a solution?

I've tried to add Append =>1 parameters to IO::Compress::Zip but the file inside the zip been overwritten ..

```
use IO::Compress::Zip qw(zip $ZipError) ;

$filenameToZip = 'file.txt';
zip $filenameToZip => "file.zip",Append => 1
    or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";
```

Do I need to decompress the zip file, append/merge the two TXT file's and compress the file again? 
Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Archive::Zip](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive::Zip) module rather than the lower-level module.  Unless you know otherwise, I would expect [IO::Compress::Zip](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Compress::Zip) to know how to do Zip-style compression, but not how to manipulate a Zip archive file.

The documentation for IO::Compress::Zip says:

> This module provides a Perl interface that allows writing zip compressed data to files or buffer.
>
> The primary purpose of this module is to provide streaming write access to zip files and buffers. It is not a general-purpose file archiver. If that is what you want, check out Archive::Zip.

Comment: this is the right module to use. sounds like maybe you want to use extractMember to get the current file out, append your other file to it using standard perl IO, then use replaceMember to replace the current text file in the archive...